# Effect of Denied Entry Stamp from Spain

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-transfer, airport-security, borders

I had a flight from Istanbul to Managua, transiting through Barcelona, Spain, and Bogotá, Colombia. I boarded my plane from Istanbul to Barcelona and made the transit. While attempting to board the second plane, the worker at the gate took my boarding pass and then told me that my transit in Colombia was more than 24 hours, so I was not allowed to board the plane. He then called the police, who investigated me and asked me to sign some papers in Spanish, which I refused. Afterwards, they put me in a detention place at the airport and sent me back to Istanbul. Upon arriving in Istanbul, they handed me my passport with a stamp on it. I would also like to mention that they refused to let me go to any other country other than Turkey. They claimed that I was only allowed to transit in Spain without a visa for 24 hours, and I had already used it. My question is, will this stamp affect me while traveling to other countries?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter for your actual question but you said that the worker stated that your transit in **Colombia** was longer than 24 hours, than at the end of your question you said the transit in **Spain** was longer than 24 hours. Which one was it?

Comment: The transit in Spain was only 4 hours. However, the one in Bogota was more than 24 hours and I did not know that transits more than 24 not allowed unless I have visa which i did not have. Therefore I was not let board the second plane and got stuck in Spain plus there were no flights going to my destination on the same day. The next day i asked them to let me buy another ticket after they have had detained me then they told me that i have been in Spain for more than 24 hours so they won’t let me go no where.

Comment: Did you get any paperwork other than the stamp? Being denied boarding shouldn’t typically affect future travel, but breaking Immigration rules could well do so. Understanding exactly what immigration offence Spanish authorities determined that you committed is very important eg for any future visa applications that ask about prior travel history

Comment: @Meedo Ad your question: this stamp will for sure invite some questions, but it shouldn't affect your future travels. You were not deported, you were refused entry before you could do anything illegal (overstaying, for example).

Comment: You were denied entry due to reason C: *(C) no valid visa or residence permit*. This is not a ban. Adding your citizenship to the question would make any proper answer easier.